# Vm is not defined - vueJS with vueCLI

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router, vue-cli-3

I'm using vue-cli for my project. vue-route and vuex also added to project. Routes working nice. while I checking vuex store data in route, I getting `vm is not defined` error. You can find the code blocks below.

main.js

```
// Application
var vm = new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')

window.vm = vm;
```

router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import auth from './controller/authController'
import Login from './views/Login.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Dashboard, beforeEnter: auth.checkAuth },
    { path: '/login', component: Login }
  ]
})
```

Problem is starting at this point. Auth js has vm defining because of reach the vuex store.

auth js

```
function checkAuth() {
  vm.$store.getters.getServerPath();
.... bla bla 
.... bla bla 
}
```

I hope some one give me an advice. If need I can share more details.

Comment: You don't need to place Vue in the window.
You can access it with `this.$store...`, `this.$router...` and so on.

Comment: @Anuga That would be that case if their auth file exists inside Vue, if it's a separate file outside of anything Vue, `this` would be nothing or the window object

Comment: Well, his calling `auth.checkAuth` before route entering, so it must be inside the VueApp.

Comment: @Anuga Calling it from inside vue doesn't always mean it will bind `this` to the vue instance

Comment: if it's in `Vue()` you can access it. Thou you need to include the Vue instance. `import vue from 'vue'` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the more standard approach in this cases is to import and export **the vuex store itself**, not the vue instance.

So in your `auth.js` you import the store and then access its getters directly:

```
import store from '@/app/store/main.store'; // or whatever path it is
function checkAuth() {
  store.getters.getServerPath();
.... bla bla 
.... bla bla 
}
```

While I believe this is better than exporting the instance (or the store) to `window`, you're asking about why `vm` is undefined in your code. Of that I'm not sure,

did you try to reference the `vm` directly from `window`? I don't really know, but vue-cli code or babel's probably set the `strict mode`, so you need to explicitly reference `window` properties from `window`:

```
function checkAuth() {
  window.vm.$store.getters.getServerPath();
.... bla bla 
.... bla bla 
}
```

Comment: Thanks sergeon, I understand what's wrong with my code. Importing vuex store is the solution for me. I can directly reach the store. So first code block of your advice is enough for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could export and import the vue instance rather than relying on the window object being available.

**main.js**

```
// Application
var vm = new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
vm.$mount('#app')

export const vueInstance = vm
```

**auth.js**

```
import { vueInstance } from '@/main'
function checkAuth() {
  vueInstance.$store.getters.getServerPath();
.... bla bla 
.... bla bla 
}
```

Comment: I tried your advice but same result. `vueInstance is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your using VueCLI3 from the mounting.
Try this, without putting it in the `window.`.

**`main.js`**

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

**`router.js`**

```
import auth from './auth'
...
{ path: '/', component: Dashboard, beforeEnter: auth.checkAuth }
```

**`auth.js`**

```
import store from './store'
...
function checkAuth() {
  store.getters.getServerPath();
}
export default checkAuth
```

Comment: I'm using auth.js already in router.js and `this` not pointing to vue. It's point on its own function.

Comment: Updated my question. router.js added.